# How to find your manual?

Tags: service-manual

Imagine that you haven't got a hard copy of your owners manual, technical data or operating instructions. Is there a good source from which you can get a PDF of the documentation online?

I'm just wondering because I bet a few people out there haven't got all of theirs!

Comment: [Helminc.com](http://www.helminc.com/helm/homepage.asp?r=) is a very good source for a lot of manuals, whether service or operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase your user & service manual from the dealer. Some older manuals may no longer be available from the manufacturer, so you will have to search eBay, clubs, etc, to find one.

[Haynes](http://www.haynes.com) creates manuals that can be purchased online or in your local automotive stores. Do your research first, some people claim that they can be better or worse than your factory manual.

[image]

Comment: Yes I guess that largely depends on how good each manufacturer bothers to make their manuals - or not as the case may be.

Comment: Couple other resources - car forums, junkyards